# How to trigger onActivityResult

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am implementing a modified version of [buttonclicker](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/ButtonClicker/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/bc/MainActivity.java) - a generic example of multiplayer android game.

There is an option for the players to go to "Quick Game", in which players seeking multiplayer games are matched randomly. I want the players to wait for 30 secs, and if no matching player is found then the player is asked to play with the computer.

Relevant code:

```
    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                     Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    
            switch (requestCode) {
                ...
    ...
                case RC_WAITING_ROOM:
                    if (responseCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        startGame(true);
                        mSYGameOn = -1;
                    } else if (responseCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM) {
                        leaveRoom();
                    } else if (responseCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        // The code that I want to execute
                        leaveRoom();
                        gotoMyPlayWithComputerCode()
                    }
                    break;
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        }
```

I believe the best way to achieve this is by triggering `onActivityResult` at the end of 30 seconds, and the execute my custom code.

The quick game is called by:

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void multiButtonFunction (String typeButton) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (typeButton) {
...
...
            case "button_quick_game":
                // user wants to play against a random opponent right now
                startQuickGame();
                break;
        }
     }
```

Now the code for the QuickGame is below. The `Handler`part of the code is what I have added to trigger `onActivityResult`, which will inturn exit the quick game screen and will then got to my custom code.:

```
 void startQuickGame() {
        final int MIN_OPPONENTS = 1, MAX_OPPONENTS = 1;
        Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(MIN_OPPONENTS,
                MAX_OPPONENTS, 0);
        RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
        rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
        rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
        rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
        keepScreenOn();
        resetGameVars();
        mSYGameOn=1;
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, rtmConfigBuilder.build());
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mSYGameOn>0) {
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, getIntent());
                }
            }
        }, 10000);
    }
```

As can be seen, I tried `setResult` but that does not work as the `onActivityResult` is not being triggered through it. Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to do the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple answer. The handler code should be:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mSYGameOn>0) {
                    finishActivity(RC_WAITING_ROOM);
                }
            }
        }, 30000);
```

This fires the `onActivityResult()` and treats the room as cancelled,exits the waiting room.

Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#optional_adding_a_waiting_room_ui)